# Hbase-database configuration

Tags: hbase

I'm new to Hbase.I have created a table using hbase shell.By default it's storing on /tmp folder. I want to change the storage location. where I should change the configuration.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Inside hbase folder there is config folder go to that there you will find a file name hbase-site.xml open it

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>home/username/hbase</value> ***<----- here you can specify the folder as storage place***
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>
```

For more options check the link below

http://hbase.apache.org/book/config.files.html

Answer (score 0):

all HBase configuration is in ${HBASE_HOME}/conf/hbase-site.xml

Look in the hbase-default.xml file for hints on what you can modify. Last I checked, that was in ${HBASE_HOME}/src/main/resources/

Answer (score 0):

you can specify some hdfs directory as the value for hbase.rootdir if you are trying to run hbase in pseudo distributed or fully distributed mode